# What does the git option remote.unfuddle.push do?

Tags: git

What changes will be made if below line is set?

`git config remote.unfuddle.push refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will configure your current repository (use the `--global` switch to perform the config for your current user account). It tells git, that for the remote `unfuddle` it should only push the `master` branch.

So `git push unfuddle` will only push `master` to the remote repository, even though other branches may exist and might have been updated (and thus pushed with the default configuration)

Comment: So, to confirm, `unfuddle` is the name of the repo, not some command ?

Comment: From the git config man page `remote.<name>.push`   
The default set of "refspec" for git-push(1). See git-push(1).

Comment: @philip: yes, `unfuddle` is the name of a configured remote (alias for a repository-url). `git config` is the command, `remote.unfuddle.push` is the key to set and `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` is the new value

Comment: When I first saw the OPs question I wondered if `unfuddle` was a command - it has the verb like feeling !